# Flutter: How to flip an icon to get mirror effect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to flip this replay material icon so that it can be used as forward.

Present Icon:

[image: Preset Icon]

Required Result:

[image]

Comment: use `Transform` widget - for more see [Transfomation Matrix](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor-help/transformation-matrix/) `*F` Mirroring

Comment: @pskink And to help with transformations: https://pub.dev/packages/matrix4_transform

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/78246965/13889070

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With Flutter 3.10.2 ( not sure if it was available before ), you can flip as below :

```dart
Transform.flip(
  flipX: true,
  child: const Icon(Icons.rotate_right),
)
```

Answer (score 184):

**Before**:

[image]

---

**After**:

[image]

```
import 'dart:math' as math; // import this

Transform(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
  child: Icon(Icons.rotate_left, size: 100,),
)
```

Comment: Awesome. To work according to locale rule, we can do `Matrix4.rotationY(isRtl() ? math.pi : 0),`

Comment: One week ago, everything was fine but after updating Flutter it shows an error that Matrix 4 is not defined

Comment: @WailHayaly Can you try this on Dartpad?

Answer (score 76):

The accepted answer works, but to add my two cents, you can use the following:

```
Transform.scale(
  scaleX: -1,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.rotate_left, 
    size: 100,
  ),
)
```

Same effect, but without an `import` statement or any explicit matrices specification

Comment: `Transform.scale` does not have the attribute `scaleX`, also it's job is to zoom- in or out the child Widget, `scale: 1.25 = 125%`

Comment: Kindly refer to the Flutter docs on [Transform.scale](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.scale.html). The `Transform.scale` has a `scaleX` attribute.

Also, the scale is meant to do what is mathematically within it's limits, which includes inverting on a particular axis if the scale < 0...

Comment: @AbdallahA.Odeh Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ISgbkZp) of the `Transform.scale` constructor...

Comment: Ooh, my bad, It's seems that is was added in the newer versions, I could not find it in my flutter! Thank you so much

Comment: This is actually better than the best answer solution. with the best answer, I had to translate it after rotating it. with This one, I didn't. thanks so much.

Answer (score -2):

Just add textDirection from right to left

```
Icon(
  Icons.reply_outlined,
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
)
```