# How To Flip An Image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

i am capturing an image by camera and want to flip that image as i show in sample picture of Giraffe.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Transform` and give the image as child,

```
 Transform(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
    child: Image.network('https://i.stack.imgur.com/VroJR.png'),
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter 3.10.2 and above versions (Don't know about the previous versions have this), you can flip as below:

```
Transform.flip(
 flipX: true, // Flip horizontally
 flipY: true, // Flip vertically
 child: Your widget,
)
```