# Mirror widget orientation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I mirror widget or image in flutter as images below[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/78246965/13889070

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this, use **Transform** Widget,
first import this

```
import 'dart:math';
```

for actual screen

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Transform(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    transform: Matrix4.rotationY(0),
    child: Image.network("https://www.vhv.rs/dpng/d/177-1771227_cartoon-figure-drawing-doremon-hd-png-download.png"),
  )
);
```

for mirror view(180 degree rotate) (that you needed)

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Transform(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
      child: Image.network("https://www.vhv.rs/dpng/d/177-1771227_cartoon-figure-drawing-doremon-hd-png-download.png"),
    )
);
```

Comment: Appreciate that!